# How to retrieve Index of all Node Resources of a speciifc content type in Drupal 7 using REST Server

Tags: json, rest

I have made this code, nut it is displaying me nodes of all content types. But i want to display nodes of a specific content type in Drupal 7?

```
$("#result8").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
          url:"http://localhost/thegosite/services/session/token",
          type:"get",
          dataType:"text",
          error:function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
          },
            success: function (token) {    
            alert(token);     
                $.ajax({
                  url: "http://localhost/thegosite/tgs_service/node/",
                  type: 'GET',
                  contentType: 'application/json',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  beforeSend: function (request) {
                        request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);
                  },
                   error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(errorThrown);
                   },
                  success: function(data) {
                    alert( "Node ID :  " + data);
                   // data.user['uid']
                }
                });
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is that you can use services views to assemble any type of views that you want, including specific content type, https://drupal.org/project/services_views